# Allure report for Java Cucumber project gives error: Could not find or load main class aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, allure

Trying to setup Allure reports for my existing project which uses Java, Selenium, TestNG, Cucumber

Below is mine pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"
            </argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

But when I run it gives me following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class javaagent:D:\Users\Lic\.m2\repository.org.aspectj.aspectjweaver.1.9.6.aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar`

Even though I'm able to see that jar in a folder

For me it looks strange that this part of path `repository.org.aspectj.aspectjweaver.1.9.6.aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar` somehow uses dots not slashes, not sure it that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that following line: `-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar" -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"` should be in the same line without newlines